How connecting all users (old & new) to maxscale proxy
I'm encountering an issue where I have set up maxscale as a database proxy.
After installing and configuration, when I connect using the maxscale user, data masking rules are applied successfully ensuring sensitive data is masked.
However, other database users connect directly to the mariadb server without going through maxscale. Consequently, data accessed by these users is not masked.
Observation:
when querying via maxscale (mysql -u maxscaleuser-P), I see masked data, but when querying via other user (mysql -u other user-p), the data is not masked.
Desired outcome:
I need all database users to connect through maxscale to ensure consistent application of data masking rule.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

From the Masking filter documentation on the applies_to rule:

With this optional key, whose value must be an array of strings, it
can be specified what users the rule is applied to. Each string should
be a MariaDB account string, that is, % is a wildcard.
If this key is not specified, then the masking is performed for all
users, except the ones exempted using the key exempted.

Removing the applies_to should make the masking happen for all users.
